# Java dice program incorrect sum of dice

Tags: java, oop, get, set, dice

I have this dice program i have been working on. It lets the user roll 2 die, then returns the value of the 2 die, and the sum of the 2 die. the first time I roll a die when running the program, it works and it adds the die up correctly, after that though, it does not add the 2 die together correctly and returns an incorrect sum of the 2 die. Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceOOP {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Die die1 = new Die();
                Die die2 = new Die();
                int total;
                char answer = 'y';
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

                while (answer == 'y') {
                        die1.roll();
                        die2.roll();
                        total = die1.getValue() + die2.getValue();
                        System.out.println("Dice 1 value is : " + die1.getSumValues());
                        System.out.println("Dice 2 value is : " + die2.getSumValues());
                        die1.reset();
                        die2.reset();
                        System.out.println("The total value rolled between both dice is: " + total);

                        System.out.println("\nDo you want to roll the dice again? (y/n)");
                        answer = scanner.next().charAt(0);
                }
        }
}
```

```
public class Die {
    public int value;
    public int sumValues;
    public int total;

    public void roll() {
        value = (int) (6 * Math.random()) + 1;
        sumValues += value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getSumValues() {
        return sumValues;
    }

    public void reset() {
    value = 0;
    total = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `getSumValues()` when you're trying to show the current *single* value?

Comment: `Die` shouldn't be keeping state based on some external logic over which it has no control. The sums of values should be determined and monitored by the caller, not `Die`. You can simplify (and error-proof) the class by giving it a *single static method* (`roll()`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you never reset `sumValues`. So the next time you role the dice `sumValues` is the sum of the old die throw with the new one. You should add this to your reset method:

```
public void reset() {
    value = 0;
    total = 0;
    sumValues = 0; //add this line

}
```

If that is what you want (Sorry I can't exactly understand what you're trying to do) then you should use `getSumValues` to calculate total like this:

```
total = die1.getSumValues() + die2.getSumValues();
```

But I think you're a bit overcomplicating. I think it's best to have the `roll` method return the value directly. And then you don't need all the other methods and fields. Or if you want you could keep the `value` field and make the `roll` method set that field and then you wouldn't need the `reset` method method (and all the other fields and methods except for `getValue`).